# Autofs only mounts on home directory

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, rhel

I'm trying to set an nfs automount with ldap in a folder other than /home.

It turns out that autofs always mounts in /home, no matter what.

I tried many configurations from the web, including from [redhats](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/nfs-autofs) but they all failed to mount the nfs export in /ldap directory.

despite /ldap folder is created it is not accessible even by root user.

Am I missing something? Should Server-side allow something specific? or is this a bug?

Linux distro: CentOS 7.0

**STEPS TOOK:**

1. make directory for ldap users mounts

   ```
   mkdir /ldap
   ```
2. enable LDAP with authconfig-tui

   ```
   authconfig-tui
   ```
3. install autofs

   ```
   yum -y install autofs
   ```
4. allow home directory creation

   ```
   authconfig --enablemkhomedir --updateall
   ```
5. update auto.master file (direct mapping)

   ```
   /misc /etc/auto.misc
   /-    /etc/auto.map   #Inserted Line
   /net  -hosts
   +dir:/etc/auto.master.d
   +auto.master
   ```

   auto.misc (untouched)

   ```
   cd    -fstype=iso9660,ro,nosuidmnodev :dev/cdrom
   ```
6. update auto.map file (created by me)

   ```
   /ldap    -fstype=nfs   server:/home/&
   ```
7. restart autofs

   ```
   systemctl restart autofs
   ```
8. login with ldap user

   ```
   su - ldapuser
   ```

**Additional Info**

on 4) I've tried both with --disablemkhomedir and with --enablemkhomedir. When using disablemkhomedir I get an error that was not possible to change to home/user directory. Even though I configured /ldap. What would make sense to me would be /ldap/ldaupuser1.

```
su: warning: cannot change directory to /home/ldapuser1: No such file or directory
```

on 7) the /ldap folder is created but I can't access the folder, even with root user. it displays:

```
cd /ldap 
-bash:cd: /ldap: No such file or directory
```

getent passwd ldapuser

```
ldapuser:*:200044:200044:LDAPUSER 1:/home/ldapuser:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Can you show all the non-comment lines from `auto.master` and `auto.misc` please. And have you edited `auto.map` at all, or is that standard?

Comment: You've got automatic home directory creation, which will be under `/home`, but you're mounting users' directories under `/ldap`. Is there a piece of the puzzle you've not shared with us, or is this part of the problem?

Comment: Hi @roaima, I have updated the post with complete uncommented auto.master,misc and map.  you mean that --enablemkhomedir can be causing the problem? I've tried both with --disablemkhomedir and with --enablemkhomedir. when using disablemkhomedir. I get an error that was not possible to create home/user directory.

Comment: Please add the output of `getent passwd ldapuser1` to your question.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I've added the requested output!

Answer (score 3):

I have two options for your , that i think might work in this scenario.

Solution1:
ON IPA SERVER:

```
# ipa user-mod ldapuser --homedir=/home/guests/ldapuser
```

change the home directory on of the user on the ipa server and then try to mount from the ipa client... it should ask you to mount into different directory.

Solution 2:  ON IPA Client

```
[root@client1 /]# showmount -e <SERVERIP>
Export list for <SERVERIP>
/home/guests *

#cat /etc/auto.master
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
/mnt   /etc/auto.nfs   <---- add this line to mount under home locally
```

create this file for nfs.

```
[root@client1 /]# cat /etc/auto.nfs
*       -fstype=nfs,rw,vers=3   192.168.20.100:/home/guests/&
```

Comment: Hi @Asif Shabbir, it doens't work either. the directory is still mounted in /home/

Comment: Have you installed NFS server . Are you able to mount NFS using mount command. I have tested above configuration and it worked for me.

Comment: Try changing this line .. /ldap -fstype=nfs server:/home/&. .  to this and check the effect .   /ldap/*  -fstype=nfs server:/home/&

Comment: Hi @Asif Shabbir, Sorry for the late reply, I only had access to the client side.But I Managed to install FreeIPA, and I'll try the solution 1. However I wanted to know if it was possible to achieve without changing the server. thank you for the help so far

Comment: and yes, I can mount the NFS directory manually